# SharePoint Foundation 2013 & Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

Current I'm working with SharePoint Foundation 2013 and I wanted to see what are the SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow limitations on the SharePoint Foundation 2013 platform? Does I have the option of creating a workflow using the 2013 workflow engine or 2010 workflow engine? What actions are available to me?

Comment: To answer to your 2nd question : Yes you can create 2013 and 2010 Workflows, both WF engines work with SP2013.

Comment: SP2013? Does include SharePoint Foundation 2013?

Comment: Yes, both foundation and server.

Comment: Do you have any official documentation that says this? Because I've seen multiple posts that this is not true.

Comment: Will provide with documentation asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can create 2013 and 2010 Workflows, both WF engines work with SP2013

This is an extract from the SharePoint 2013 Core Development Trainer Handbook. Sorry, I didn't find what I want from the web, but I'll keep looking for a valid answer.

[image]